# Problem with subdividing an octagon

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I found a weird problem - when applying a subdivision (in this case level 2, but it happens with any level) on the octagon, there is a strange pinching happening in two opposite corners.

Before:

[image: Before:]

And after:

[image: And after:]

Scale and rotation are applied if this could be related.

I'd really appreciate any tip on how to fix this!

Comment: Can you share your blend file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: You should add more details about the way your mesh was made in order to get a better picture of your problem. add as many images and information as you can. the more the better.

Comment: It is not strange as long as we don't know how you created it... things that could cause this: the edges there have a crease set, the edges are split there, duplicate vertices in this area etc.

Comment: try going into edit mode and pressing `a` to select all then `m` > *Merge By Distance*

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, so you must have overlapping vertices or inner faces, please share your file

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions! That was a long night and I was too tired to check one of the basic things one should check before posting a question - face orientation! For some reason, half of the mesh was facing the other direction, so I recalculated normals and subdivision started working properly!

Answer (score 1):

Face orientation was wrong, so I needed to recalculate normals. After that everything worked properly.